# Importing JSON data to D3.js + Google Map through an internal array

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am now trying an example of D3.js called "Google Maps + D3" (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/899711). In the sample code, the data is imported with an external JSON file (stations.json). Would it be possible to load the data with an array? I have modified the code as follows, but it does not work. Thanks for any solutions provided.

```html
var data = [{"KMAE":[-120.12,36.98,"MADERA MUNICIPAL AIRPORT",[26,1,2,5,6,3,2,1,2,7,29,12,3]],"KSJC":[-121.92,37.37,"SAN JOSE INTERNATIONAL  AIRPORT",[28,1,1,1,6,10,5,3,2,4,14,21,7]],"KMCE":[-120.50,37.28,"MERCED MUNICIPAL AIRPORT",[29,1,1,3,7,5,2,1,3,6,12,26,5]],"KMER":[-120.57,37.37,"Merced / Castle Air Force Base",[34,1,1,1,4,5,2,1,1,4,17,22,7]],"KAPC":[-122.28,38.20,"NAPA COUNTY AIRPORT",[23,2,1,6,3,3,8,18,11,13,4,3,5]],"KSUU":[-121.95,38.27,"Fairfield / Travis Air Force Base",[13,7,4,3,3,6,4,13,33,4,1,2,7]],"KSQL":[-122.25,37.52,"San Carlos Airport",[18,3,2,2,3,4,3,2,5,17,16,12,12]],"KSNS":[-121.60,36.67,"SALINAS MUNICIPAL AIRPORT",[21,1,1,6,12,3,1,2,9,21,17,5,1]],"KMOD":[-120.95,37.62,"MODESTO CITY CO SHAM FLD",[27,1,1,2,10,5,1,1,1,3,17,24,8]],"KOAK":[-122.23,37.72,"METRO OAKLAND INTERNATIONAL  AIRPORT ",[16,3,3,2,4,6,3,4,9,23,20,6,2]],"KSCK":[-121.23,37.90,"STOCKTON METROPOLITAN AIRPORT ",[21,2,2,3,6,8,2,1,4,15,19,12,4]],"KCCR":[-122.05,38.00,"CONCORD BUCHANAN FIELD",[24,3,2,1,1,5,17,12,9,9,7,6,4]],"KMRY":[-121.85,36.58,"MONTEREY PENINSULA AIRPORT",[26,1,2,9,5,3,4,9,13,14,9,4,1]],"KPAO":[-122.12,37.47,"Palo Alto Airport",[31,3,1,1,2,5,1,1,1,4,10,25,14]],"KSAC":[-121.50,38.50,"SACRAMENTO EXECUTIVE AIRPORT ",[32,1,0,1,3,11,12,16,5,2,4,9,3]],"KHWD":[-122.12,37.67,"HAYWARD AIR TERMINAL",[20,2,7,2,2,6,3,3,6,23,18,6,2]],"KSTS":[-122.82,38.50,"SANTA ROSA SONOMA COUNTY",[46,1,0,1,5,13,10,4,3,3,4,6,3]],"KSMF":[-121.60,38.70,"SACRAMENTO INTERNATIONAL  AIRPORT",[19,2,1,2,4,21,18,8,3,2,5,12,4]],"KNUQ":[-122.05,37.43,"MOFFETT FIELD",[35,3,1,1,4,7,2,1,2,5,6,17,15]],"KRHV":[-121.82,37.33,"San Jose / Reid / Hillv",[35,0,0,1,4,4,2,1,1,10,28,11,1]],"KWVI":[-121.78,36.93,"WATSONVILLE MUNICIPAL AIRPORT ",[44,1,2,3,4,5,7,9,8,4,6,5,2]],"KMHR":[-121.30,38.55,"Sacramento, Sacramento Mather Airport",[21,1,1,2,8,15,12,12,7,4,5,7,3]],"KVCB":[-121.95,38.38,"VACAVILLE NUT TREE AIRPORT",[36,2,1,1,2,6,10,18,10,2,2,5,6]],"KSFO":[-122.37,37.62,"SAN FRANCISCO INTERNATIONAL  AIRPORT ",[13,3,3,2,3,4,4,4,7,31,20,2,3]],"KLVK":[-121.82,37.70,"LIVERMORE MUNICIPAL AIRPORT ",[32,2,7,3,1,1,2,7,9,17,16,2,1]]}
];

        if (error) throw error;

        var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

        // Add the container when the overlay is added to the map.
        overlay.onAdd = function () {
            var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div")
            .attr("class", "stations");

            // Draw each marker as a separate SVG element.
            // We could use a single SVG, but what size would it have?
            overlay.draw = function () {
                var projection = this.getProjection(),
              padding = 10;

            var marker = layer.selectAll("svg")
              .data(d3.entries(data))
              .each(transform) // update existing markers
            .enter().append("svg")
              .each(transform)
              .attr("class", "marker");

                // Add a circle.
                marker.append("circle")
              .attr("r", 4.5)
              .attr("cx", padding)
              .attr("cy", padding);

                // Add a label.
                marker.append("text")
              .attr("x", padding + 7)
              .attr("y", padding)
              .attr("dy", ".31em")
              .text(function (d) { return d.key; });

                function transform(d) {
                    d = new google.maps.LatLng(d.value[1], d.value[0]);
                    d = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(d);
                    return d3.select(this)
                .style("left", (d.x - padding) + "px")
                .style("top", (d.y - padding) + "px");
                }
            };
        };

        // Bind our overlay to the map…
        overlay.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the result: https://plnkr.co/edit/l3LgQnGRVp6kJZMSgtue?p=preview

You can replace the function with your custom one and call that with your local data like this:

```
var data = {"KMAE":[..
mapFunction(data);
// Load the station data. When the data comes back, create an overlay.
function mapFunction(data) {..
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution, echonax!